# Is it possible to edit a sharepoint online excel file using EPPlus and C#?

Tags: c#, powershell, sharepoint, epplus

I have some C# console apps and powershell scripts that read and sometimes modify excel files using EPPlus/ OpenXml.

These files are being moved from network drive to Sharepoint online 365.

What are my options for editing these files?

I have seen a couple of libraries like PnPPowershell, CSOM, that I could use to download, modify and and upload the files.

Is there any possibility to map to sharepoint like a mapped network or PSDrive and just edit in place?

Comment: Did you find out is it possible or not?

Comment: I ended up using PnPPowershell as above. How about an upvote and some else might see this question and answer it.